# Servicestack Razor, setting Layout to Null

Tags: razor, servicestack

Using ServiceStack.Razor and having a slight issue.

I have a default `_Layout.cshtml` page that is my base layout, but for some pages, I don't want a layout, I just want to a full html page with no templating, similar to how setting the Layout to null in ASP.NET MVC would work.

I cannot figure out how to do this, and can't find anything in the [documentation](http://razor.servicestack.net/) (not saying it's not there, just can't find it).

Things I've tried:

1. Setting the Layout property to null on the actual view page:

   `@{
       Layout = null;
    }`
2. Returning a null template from the actual service:

   `return HttpResult(dto) { Template = null; };`
3. Moving my view page out of the Views folder (this just took it back to the default ServiceStack view page)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, and sorry if I missed something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Layout=null` indicates no Layout was specified, so will use the default `_Layout.cshtml`.

You can use an empty string `""` for no Layout, e.g:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```

Otherwise if preferred, create an `"Empty"` layout e.g: `/Views/Shared/Empty.cshtml` containing just:

```
@RenderBody()
```